# Craft redirects to domain.tld/domain.tld/ on logout

Tags: craft3, users, session, usermodel

I have a logout button on my site that points to the `logoutUrl`.

While the logout works and ends the user session, the user is brought to a page with the URL similar to `domain.tld/domain.tld/` where domain.tld is my test-server's domain.

Naturally, this results in a 404 since I don't have a template to render a matching URL.

Any idea how to fix this or what could be causing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a bit of trial an error, setting a protocol for the `siteUrl` in `config/general.php` fixed it!

Ex. I had `'siteUrl' => 'domain.tld'` so I changed it to `'siteUrl' => '//domain.tld'` and all is well.